# Python Simple-Salesforce - Import related records with an external ID

Tags: data-loader, data, python, simple-salesforce

Some time ago I've started to use Python with Pandas and Simple-Salesforce to make data migration to Salesforce orgs.
I want to insert Account records and Contact records that have lookup to Account records. Instead of a Salesforce record ID of a related record, I want to use an external ID to associate/connect records.
When I'm making this kind of insert operation for Contact records with Salesforce Inspector instead of using `AccountId` field I can use `Account.ExternalId__c`, with Data Loader it's `Account:ExternalId__c`.

What is a notation that should be used for `simple-salesforce`? When I'm using `Account.ExternalId__c` or `Account:ExternalId__c` I'm receiving this error:

> simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request _https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/services/async/42.0/job/some_id/batch/some_id2/result. Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch', 'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}

I'm using this `simple-salesforce` method to insert records:

```
sf.bulk.Account.insert(data_json, batch_size=100, use_serial=False)
```

Of course when I'm trying to import related records by Data Loader or Salesforce Inspector everything is working fine, so I'm guessing that it's issue with notation in Simple-Salesforce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upsert new records into a custom object using Salesforce REST API which has "Look-Up" relationship with Contact using External ID?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362962/how-to-upsert-new-records-into-a-custom-object-using-salesforce-rest-api-which-h)

Comment: Thanks @identigral ! You're right - It's similar and gave me some additional idea to resolve my issue. I'll paste explanation in separate answer. It's to long to include it here.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution and explanation if someone will looking for this in the future.

Previous version of my data_json:

```
data_json = {'FirstName': 'Test 1', 
             'LastName': 'Name 1', 
             'Email': 'test01@test.com', 
             'AccountId': 'someAccountId'}
```

I had to:

- rename 'AccountId' key to 'Account'
- create new dictionary: extIdDict = {'ExternalId__c': 'someExternalId'}
- add extIdDict dictionary as a value to 'Account' key: row['Account'] = extIdDict

Finally, I have data_json like this:

```
data_json = {'FirstName': 'Test 1', 
             'LastName': 'Name 1', 
             'Email': 'test01@test.com', 
             'Account': {'ExternalId__c': 'someExternalId'}}
```

With this kind of json I was able to use it as a parameter in insert method mentioned in my original question and successfully insert contact records linked with account records.